# Simulink model to draw automatically the even and odd parts of the signal x(t)

Tags: matlab, math, simulink

I want to make a model that draws the even and the odd part of the signal, 
mathematically I can get the even and odd parts by getting the inverted signal:

x<sub>even</sub>(t) = [ x(t) + x(-t) ] / 2

x<sub>odd</sub>(t) = [ x(t) - x(-t) ] / 2

Now I can't get the inverted signal x(-t) in Matlab Simulink.
Any other ideas how can I get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to do it on a sample by sample basis as there's no concept of negative time.

But you can buffer the signal (into a vector of N points) and then use the equivalent discrete time formulae to calculate odd and even components centered around the N/2 sample.

Both the buffering and the odd/even calculation can be done using a MATLAB Function block.